# how to get all post of my facebook application?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i want to get all post published from my application.

```
$fql = "SELECT post_id, app_id,attribution,message WHERE source_id = 188600424497292";
    $param = array (
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
    'callback' => ""
    );
    $fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);


    echo "<pre>";print_r($fqlResult); echo "</pre>";
```

can any body help?
thanks

Comment: can you explain us what output you got and what actually you want to get?

Comment: i want to get all the post which are published from my application.

Comment: what output you got while trying this?

Comment: in documentation it is written that source_id can only be   The ID of the user, page, group, or event whose wall the post is on. there is no application id.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you really need, But you can use this in future reference.

This is how we usually do to get the count of the posts or shares done by the application, we have our own local db with the count get increased whenever there is a post.

Here is a sample function which will post to users wall and on success we are calling a function through ajax call and inserting the count.

```
function shareToOwnWall()
{
    FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'feed',
                name: 'name of the app',
                picture: 'picture',
                caption: ' ',
                description: 'description',
                link : 'appurl'
            },
            function(response) {
                    if(response != false) {
                        jQuery.ajax({
                           url: 'module/action',
                           type: "POST",
                           data: {app_id: <?php echo $appId ?> ,shareCount: 1, signed_request: '<?php echo $_REQUEST['signed_request']?>'},
                           success: function (resp){
                           }
                       });
                    }
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: but what to do with the post that already published. how do i track them?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about how to get it. But you can use the above code for upcoming applications. I will let you know if I found any solution for the above scenario.

Comment: thanks alot i will be waiting for your response. Don't we have any facebook moderator here??? can any body help please.